# Apache Hive- Time Stamp query

Tags: hive, timestamp

I have two time stamp columns in a Hive DB storing timestamp in following format:

```
hive> select last_date from xyz limit 2;  
OK
2019-08-21 15:11:23.553
2019-08-21 15:11:23.553
```

[Above has milliseconds stored in it by default]

```
hive> select last_modify_date from xyz limit 2;
OK
2018-04-18 23:32:58
2017-09-22 04:02:32
```

I need a common Hive select query which would convert both the above timestamps to 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.SSS' formats, preserving the millisecond value if exists, or appending '.000' if it doesnt exist.

What I have tried so far:

```
select 
    last_modify_date, 
    from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(last_modify_date), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS") as ts 
from xyz limit 3;
```

However, the above query displays '.000' for both the above said timestamp columns.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

From the [UDF](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/branch-1.1.1/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDFToUnixTimeStamp.java) that implements `unix_timestamp`, you can see that the returned value is in SENCONDS represented by a `LongWritable`. And anything less than one second is rounded off.

You can write your own UDF, or just use pure SQL to achieve that.
One of the easy way is to use the [GenericUDFRpad](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDFRpad.java) `rpad`:

```
    select rpad(your_date, 23, '.000') from your_table;
```

Some examples:

```
    hive> select rpad('2018-04-18 23:32:58', 23, '.000');
    OK
    2018-04-18 23:32:58.000
    hive> select rpad('2018-04-18 23:32:58.553', 23, '.000');
    OK
    2018-04-18 23:32:58.553
```